# -20 shutdown, what to do?

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, restart

Comp just shut down. Checked the logs and it says:

> Previous shutdown cause: -20

A [shutdown causes](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/) page says:

> -20    BridgeOS T2-initiated shutdown. The T2 chip in your 2018+ MacBook Pro or other Mac (list in link) initiated a shutdown.

This is a fairly new computer, I'm not sure what's going on. I've experienced a bunch of `x86 CPU CATERR detected` and `AppleEmbeddedPCIeUpLinkMgmt` kernel panics.

Should I just go and get it checked out?

Comment: Most definitely!  The fact you’re seeing hardware related kernel panics is concerning. Get it checked out especially if it’s still under warranty

Answer (score 4):

Just as an update because this question keeps getting upvoted:

it was a logic board issue - apple replaced the logic board under warranty definitely don't sleep on this issue

Answer (score 3):

Fairly new computer I would 100% talk with Apple support online to see what they recommend. Might be fine, but why not take advantage of the paid support for new hardware.